# How to show day from input date in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show day into textbox based on my input date

here is my ajax to change the textbox :

```html
$("#date").change(function(){
            
        $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo base_url();?>daftar/get_day",
                method : "POST",
                data : {date: $("#date").val()},
                async : false,
               
                success: function(data){
                
                    $("#day").val(day);
                
                }
                
            });
            
        
            
        });
```

this is my controller :

```html
function get_day()
    {
        $date=$this->input->post('date');
        
        $this->load-model('daftarmodel');
        $day = $this->daftarmodel->geDay($date);
        
        echo $day;
      
    }
```

this is my model :

```html
function getDay($date){
        
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);

        $day = date('D', $timestamp);
        var_dump($day);
        
        return $day;
        
        
    }
```

is there anything wrong with my code which not showing the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the part of your problem, but looks like you may be using the wrong variable in your ajax success.

```html
success: function(data){
   $("#day").val(day);
}
```

you could try replacing "day" with the "data" variable that is in your: "success: function(data)"

```
success: function(data){
   $("#day").val(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all you need to remove var_dump($day); from your model.
> Secondly need to little bit improvement in your understanding . Ajax
> call return response in case of successfully execution ajax return result
> in success function. In your case it will return day in data.

```
success: function(data){ 
    $("#day").val(data);            
}
```